# can be used Material Design för Bootstrap and angular material in a single angular project

Tags: angular-material, angular6

I have a question, I just started a project angular 6,

I thought of using Material Design for Bootstrap and Angular Material.

my question is: it's good to use both at the same time for a project angular

thank you!!

Comment: you can use them both, the CSS would clash since Angular-Material components would be governed by AM-css and Bootstrap components by bootstrap-css

Answer (score 0):

i am also using bootstrap grid css and angular mat in same project

https://github.com/dmhendricks/bootstrap-grid-css/tree/master/dist/css